# make variable as field name sql using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

With this data:

```
id | month    | 2015 | 2014 | 2013
1  | january  | 2    | 4    | 6  
2  | february | 10   | 12   | 14
3  | march    | 16   | 18   | 20
```

I have vb.net code here

```
Dim asd As Double = 2015
Dim msg As Double

sql = "select " & asd & " from tbl_coll_penalty where month = 'february'"
sda = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, pgConnection)
sda.Fill(DS, "t")

msg = DS.Tables("t").Rows(0)(0).ToString()
MessageBox.Show(msg)
```

I got wrong answer with this code because the answer of this code is "2015" but I expect the answer to be "10". Can someone help me the proper code of this?

Comment: why won't you just add a fieldname "year" and another fieldname for the data under each year so you can have your query like this>>> select data from tbl_coll_penalty where month='february' and year="' & asd & '" ???

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, your column name "2015" is interpreted as a literal value. So when you submit the query:

```
SELECT 2015 FROM tbl_coll_penalty ...
```

you simply get the value 2015 back.

In the SQL standard, a column identifier cannot start with a numeral (0..9). Check the documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html). To have PostgreSQL interpret the string "2015" as a column name, you should double-quote it:

```
sql = "select """ & asd & """ from tbl_coll_penalty where month = 'february'"
```

Comment: sir in my postgre 2015 field datatype is double precision. i got error function quote_ident(integer) does not exist

Comment: `quote_ident()` is indeed expecting a string, so that won't work. Only sensible option is then to get the column name double-quoted. See updated answer. Not pretty at all. If you can, change your column names.

Comment: i cant change my column name because their is a reason why i used that structure .

Comment: @MichaelBeray, you should to do explicit cast ` select quote_ident(2015::text);` or you can use a format function `select format('select %I from foo', 2015);`

Comment: Dim asd As Double = 2014
        Dim msg As Double
        sql = "select ""2014"" from tbl_coll_penalty where month = 'May'"
        sda = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, pgConnection)
        sda.Fill(DS, "t")
        msg = DS.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)
        MessageBox.Show(msg)

Answer (score 0):

I am too late to answer this question but...

Change your query as per below

sql = "select [" & asd & "] from tbl_coll_penalty where month = 'february'"

I tested it with ms-access table and it worked
It should work with your query too. I think so...